# devenv treating path from variable substituted with space as 2 parameters when run from batch file to build a C# solution

Tags: c#, batch-file, solution, devenv

```
set "var=%cd%"
devenv "%var%"\example.sln /rebuild
```

here if we have solution example.sln at a path like and

> c:\test\path withSpace\example.sln

and we assume that we run the batch file for the path

> c:\test\path withSpace

I am getting the error:

The following files were specified on the command line:

> c:\test\path withSpace
>
> \example.sln

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this I changed:

```
devenv "%var%"\example.sln /rebuild
```

to

```
devenv "%var%\example.sln" /rebuild
```

Note the location of closing double quote

Comment: I was confused on what to do as I had tried lot of options today. Finally when i was about to post the question on SO, the answer unravelled, so I posted both question and the answer so that someone could benifit in the future.